Calculate width of divided container
I'm trying to set the width of the striped area in my drawing below, so that it falls within the bounds of the site content.
The width of the content is 80%, with a maximum width of 1080px, and centered (illustrated below in purple). The columns are variable widths, but together always fill the width of the page - I used 75%/25% in the illustration below to simplify, but the widths of the actual page are included in the following code snippet.


:root {
  --column-width-multiplier: 8.333;
  --column-gap: 2.13%;
}

/* Making it look nice */
h2 {text-align: center}
body {width: 100%; margin: 0;background-color: #ff48a6; color: #fff; font-family: monospace; font-size: 16px;}
.row-fluid {display: flex; justify-content: space-between;}
.site-container {border: 4px solid #a64df5; background-color: #a64df570;}
.side-a {border: 2px solid #bff661;}
.side-b {border: 2px solid #caf87a;}
/* End making it look nice */

.site-container {
  max-width: 1080px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.span5 {
  width: calc(var(--column-width-multiplier) * 1% * 5 - var(--column-gap) * (7 * var(--column-width-multiplier) / 100))
}

.span7 {
  width: calc(var(--column-width-multiplier) * 1% * 7 - var(--column-gap) * (5 * var(--column-width-multiplier) / 100));
}

.side-b .site-container {
  float: left;
/*   TODO: Add width dimensions to make this fall inside content container */
}
<body>
  <h2>Divided Container</h2>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="side-a span5">
      We don't need this stuff to fall within the site container
    </div>
    <div class="side-b span7">
      <div class="site-container">
        This is the content that need to fit within the content container at every breakpoint!!!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="normal-section">
    <h2>Normal Section</h2>
    <div class="site-container">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et fermentum dui. Ut orci quam, ornare sed lorem sed, hendrerit auctor dolor. Nulla viverra, nibh quis ultrices malesuada, ligula ipsum vulputate diam, aliquam egestas nibh ante vel dui. Sed in tellus interdum eros vulputate.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>



What is the algorithm to achieve this? I want the CSS width assignment to work for any column size.


I can’t see what the problem is here so I must be missing something. Can you explain a bit more, preferably with some code example. In your diagram the width of the rightmost, unstriped bit is 10%. So the width of the striped bit is 25%-10%=15%.

right-box = 10% + 80% = 90%; left-box = 75%; width = right-box - left-box = 90% - 75% = 15%.

I think they are saying that you didn't explain the full problem.  If I'm understanding your question correctly: You have a page that is currently split 75%/25% (or at least in your example), and you want to put content that is centered to the full page and takes up 80%, in such a way that some of that 80% will be on the 75% side and some will be on the 25% side? And you want to know  how to calculate that 80% width?

Oh even more than that: You want to know how to calculate the width of the part of your 80% that overlaps with the side that is 25%. At the very least, just dividing for the calculation won't do, as you are finding a difference, meaning you'll need to do some subtraction as well.

@Anthony there is no needs to complicate this calculation, 80% of 100vw = 80vw and 15% of 100vw = 15vw

@MisterJojo why haven't you answered yet?

@Anthony answered  on what?

There are two scenarios we need to include in the calculation.

Wide screens, when the content width is constrained to 1080px
Narrow screens, when the content width is 80%

The screenshot below illustrates the setup:

yellow represents the viewport width (100vw)
pink represents the left column (75vw)
red represents the right column (25vw)
lime represents the content (the minimum of 1080px and 80vw)
the white striped area is the width you are wanting to calculate, which is the portion of the content which would overlap the right column


So for scenario 1, the width of the striped area is the width of the red area minus the width of the white area underneath the red area. To get the width of the white area we subtract the width of the lime area from the viewport width, then divide by two (because there are white areas on both sides). The equation for this scenario is therefore:
stripeWidth = redWidth - ((yellowWidth - limeWidth) / 2)

For scenario 2 it’s simpler, because we know that the white area is simply 10vw, so the equation for this scenario is:
stripeWidth = redWidth - 10vw = 25vw - 10vw = 15vw

For the overall equation we just need to take whichever of these two results has the smaller value. The CSS representation of the equation uses both min() and calc():
.striped {
  width: min(15vw, calc(25vw - ((100vw - var(--content-width)) / 2)));
}

Here is a working snippet to demonstrate:


const f = document.querySelector('.full')
const l = document.querySelector('.left')
const r = document.querySelector('.right')
const c1 = document.querySelector('.c1')
const s = document.querySelector('.striped')

const displayWidths = () => {
  f.innerHTML = f.offsetWidth
  l.innerHTML = l.offsetWidth
  r.innerHTML = r.offsetWidth
  c1.innerHTML = c1.offsetWidth
  s.innerHTML = s.offsetWidth
}

addEventListener('resize', displayWidths)

displayWidths()
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
  --content-width: 1080px;
}

.full, .left, .right, .c1, .c2, .striped {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.full {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  background: yellow;
}

.left {
  background: pink;
}

.right {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.c1, .c2 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  width: min(var(--content-width), 80%);
  justify-self: center;
}

.c1 {
  background: lime;
}

.c2 {
  background: cyan;
  align-self: end;
  justify-content: end;
}

.striped {
  color: black;
  width: min(15vw, calc(25vw - ((100vw - var(--content-width)) / 2)));
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 5%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 5%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 10%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 10%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 15%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 15%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 20%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 20%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 25%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 25%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 30%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 30%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 35%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 35%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 40%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 40%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 45%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 45%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 50%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 50%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 55%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 55%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 60%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 60%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 65%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 65%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 70%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 70%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 75%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 75%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 80%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 80%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 85%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 85%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 90%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 90%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 95%, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 95%);  
}
<div class="full"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="c1"></div>
<div class="c2">
  <div class="striped">X</div>
</div>



After running this snippet, use the full page link to test the responsive behaviour.

Say the container's width is always 100% (or rather 100vw), in that case
stripedWidth = 25vw     // but...

would suffice. But, since the container's width is limited to a max-width (of 1080px), keeping the striped element width at 25vw would make it too large - as we incremented the viewport width.
Therefore the question is:

"By how much do we need to subtract from 25vw (stripes width)"?

Setting the striped element's width to 25vw and slowly resizing the viewport the answer would become immediately visible and obvious:


we need to reduce that 25vw by exactly one margin's width (that one space between the container edge and the viewport's edge).

margin = (viewport.width - container.width) / 2

Solution:
.striped {
  width: calc(25vw - (100vw - 100%) / 2);
}

Example:


* { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 75%, #ccc 75%);
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 480px; /* DEMO ONLY, you use 1080px */
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.striped {
  margin-left: auto;
  width: calc(25vw - (100vw - 100%) / 2);
  /* min-width: 50px; /* Uncomment if necessary */
  min-height: 4rem;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(160deg,#0000,#0000 10px,#f80 10px,#f80 15px);
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="striped"></div>
</div>

Resize the viewport to test .striped width



Tip:
if you cannot use body but you have another parent which width does not match 100vw, then use container-type: size; on that element, and change vw units from the above code into cqw (container-query units) - and will work the same.
